# Error with ANT profiler Methods must be security critical or security safe-critical to call native code

Tags: c#, http, profiler, red-gate-ants

This works fine on my machine, but we have 2 other machines that will not work with the ANTS Profiler from Redgate

I have raised a question on their forums but this is holding us up so I am raising this here in the hope there may be a change we can make our side

**System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource, Boolean)' 
to call native code through method '._ANTS_Begin_Async()' failed.

Methods must be security critical or security safe-critical to call native code.**

The application makes a call to a service fabric endpoint via a http call

Paul